# Issue executing a piped ps unix command through Runtime.exec()

Tags: java, unix, runtime.exec, java-6

#### Issue:

When executing the following command through `Runtime.exec(...)`, it fails with an unexpected EOF while looking for a matching quote character.

One oddity is that the error message has a grave character followed by two single quotes.

However, when I execute the command that prints out in the logs through putty, it works fine.

#### Command:

```
bin/sh -c 'ps -eo uname,pid,ppid,nlwp,pcpu,pmem,psr,start_time,tty,time,args | fgrep IAAPC | fgrep /f1/f2/a00-a/f3/server/server_1/env_1/javadriver | fgrep -v fgrep'
```

#### Resulting error:

```
-eo: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
-eo: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

#### Java Code (Java 1.6 ... Don't Judge):

```
    String driverHome = trimToEmpty(System.getProperty("batchdriver.home"));
    String cmd = "/bin/sh -c 'ps -eo uname,pid,ppid,nlwp,pcpu,pmem,psr,start_time,tty,time,args | fgrep "+jobName+" | fgrep "+driverHome+" | fgrep -v fgrep'";
    String out = null, err = null;
    Process proc = null;
    try {
        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        
        out = fullyRead(proc.getInputStream());
        err = fullyRead(proc.getErrorStream());
        
        int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
        
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Process Information: "+out);
        }
        if (isNotEmpty(err)) {
            logger.error(failedCommandMessage(cmd, out, err));
            this.processId = null;
            this.processDesc = PROCESS_NOT_FOUND;
            return;
        }
        
        String[] processes = StringUtils.split(out, "\r?\n");
        if (processes == null || processes.length == 0) {
            this.processDesc = PROCESS_NOT_FOUND;
        }
        else if (processes.length == 1) {
            String[] processInfo = processes[0].split("\\s+");
            this.processId = processInfo[1];
            if (!isNumeric(this.processId)) {
                this.processId = null;
            }
            this.processDesc = out;
        }
        else {
            this.processDesc = out;
        }
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Call to the OS completed with exit value: " + exitVal);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {out = fullyRead(proc.getInputStream());} catch (Exception e1) {}
        try {err = fullyRead(proc.getErrorStream());} catch (Exception e1) {}
        this.processId = null;
        this.processDesc = PROCESS_NOT_FOUND;
        logger.error(failedCommandMessage(cmd, out, err), e);
    }
```

Comment: The back-quote, single-quote, single-quote is just the way that this tool outputs items it want to "quote". Unfortunately, many other tools use this format as well, but I suppose it avoids ambiguity in cases where the missing char is `"` (and others probably). For you case, you can think that the error message is just ending in `"'"` (dbl-quote, single-quote, dbl-quote), and that `'` is the problematic character. Why that is happening is beyond my paygrade. Good luck.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related but not quite dupe: [Pass a string with multiple contiguous spaces as a parameter to a jar file using Windows command prompt called from a java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31195623/pass-a-string-with-multiple-contiguous-spaces-as-a-parameter-to-a-jar-file-using)

[The `Runtime.exec` methods that take a `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.io.File-) break it into tokens [at whitespace only](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer-java.lang.String-) so this actually runs the program `/bin/sh` (a shell) with the following arguments:

```
 -c
 'ps
 -eo 
 uname,pid,ppid,nlwp,pcpu,pmem,psr,start_time,tty,time,args 
 |
 fgrep
 ...
```

The shell interprets these arguments like this:

```
 -c 'ps -- the script to run consists of the apostrophe character, p, s (and nothing more)
 -eo -- the name of the command being run is -eo 
 uname,pid,.... -- the first argument to the script is this
 | -- the second argument to the script is this
 fgrep -- the third argument to the script is this
 ... 
 -- but the script ignores the arguments and doesn't use them
```

Thus you get

```
-eo: -c: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
# the script named -eo, with the option -c having value 'ps,
# tried to find a closing ' to match the opening ' and it's not there
```

This shell is apparently (GNU) bash; many GNU programs that put a data string in an error message surround it by backquote and apostrophe because these were sort of matching quotes in one interpretation of ASCII popular decades ago.

Instead use [the `String[]` overload of `exec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-) to give the shell the two arguments that it gets when your above command line is parsed *by a shell* instead of `StringTokenizer`:

```
 String[] cmdary = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "ps -eo stuff | fgrep this | fgrep that | fgrep -v fgrep"};
 ... Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdary);
```

But instead of running three fgrep's, you could just run the `ps` and read the inputstream as lines and test them in Java using `String.contains` or similar. Also most of the columns you ask `ps` for will never be used for either your matching *nor* result, so that's just a waste of effort and clutter.

Comment: Testing passing the String array, next.

Don't want to process the full results of the ps commind in java due to the large number of records and the number of processes that will be executing this if I don't have to.

Once we upgrade our Java version, I'll be able to use better tools, but for now this is what I've got.

Comment: Using the String array fixed it. Thanks.